# Can I add a title to survival.plot?

Tags: r

I used `Survival.plot` to create my comparison survival curves and want to add a title. Can I do this with this function?

```
library(ComparisonSurv)

Survival.plot(
  dat$Primary.to.outcomes..Years., 
  dat$Censor, 
  dat$Cemented.Stem., 
  xlab = "Time (Years)", 
  ylab = "Survival", 
  col = c(1, 4), 
  lwd = c(3, 3), 
  lty= c(1, 1)
)
legend(
  2.5, 
  1, 
  c("no", "yes"), 
  col = c(1, 4), 
  lwd = c(3, 3), 
  lty= c(1, 1), 
  bty="n"
)
```

Comment: Survival.plot(dat$Primary.to.outcomes..Years., dat$Censor, dat$Cemented.Stem., xlab = "Time (Years)", ylab = "Survival"
, col = c(1, 4), lwd = c(3, 3), lty= c(1, 1))
legend(2.5, 1, c("no", "yes"), col = c(1, 4), lwd = c(3, 3), lty= c(1, 1), bty="n", title = "DAT: No vs. Yes")  - I tried adding a title argument but R ignores it

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ComparisonSurv/versions/1.1.1/topics/Survival.plot), you should be able to use `Survival.plot(..., main = "Your Title")`. (Look for the entry "... Parameters in function plot()" meaning you can use the generic plot arguments, like `main` for this function, too. (see `?plot.default`)

Comment: you can also use `title(main = ...)` it looks like this function is just a very simple wrapper of [`plot.survfit`](https://github.com/cran/ComparisonSurv/blob/master/R/ComparisonSurv.R#L799:L800) anyway so i would just use that and not worry about the package. also you can have more than 2 groups and they need not be coded 0/1, that is also a questionable choice for that package